# String manipulations with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have this string:

```
Table {is {red|blue|orange|white|green-{yellow|black}} |has {{twenty|thirty}two|{{two hundered and |three hundered and }fourty |fifty }three|four} legs} and is placed { in corner | in the middle } of office and {printer|phone} is {{gray-|}black|white}.
```

I want some data structure that I would be able to work with it, Can you suggest something?

This is my try:

```
var matches = $scope.fileContent.match(/{([^}]+)}/g);

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
   console.log(matches[i]);
}
```

I want random sentences

Possible results:

```
 - Table is blue and is placed in corner of office and printer is black.
 - Table has three hundered and fourty three legs and is placed in the middle of office and phone is gray-black.
```

Comment: So you want to generate random sentences ?

Comment: What have you tried? And what's the specific goal here? `able to work with` is pretty open-ended.

Comment: It looks like you want some kind of templating/random data selection library, but this is rather broad for SO (seems like a software recommendation). Personally, I would grab an off-the-shelf template library (handlebars, for example) and feed it random data.

Comment: I need some kind of algorithm and implementation,  I haven't succeeded to find any solution

Comment: Make it into a tree, traverse, and branch randomly

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson can you refer me to an example?

Comment: I would have recommended an approach with JSON, but the structure I was experimenting with got messy _really_ quickly.

Comment: I'm still trying to work out a grammar for this...

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grammar for this sort of sentence structure would be:

```
SENTENCE     := PARTIAL optional SENTENCE
PARTIAL      := TEXT or BRANCH
BRANCH       := '{' SENTENCE ALTERNATIVES '}'
ALTERNATIVES := '|' SENTENCE optional ALTERNATIVES
```

Maybe I could have used clearer names for the different stages, but you get the point. Any of your sentences can be broken down using the rules of this grammar. After parsing, you will get your sentence in a tree structure.

Once you have your string parsed into this tree structure, you can traverse it, and pick randomly as to which branch you take. An example in JavaScript:

```
var string = "A table {is {red|blue|green}|has {four|five} legs}"
var index = 0
var root = new Node()
var current = root

function Node() {
    this.text = ""
    this.options = []
    this.next = null
}

Node.prototype.toString = function(){
    var string = this.text;
    if (this.options.length > 0) {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.options.length)
        string += this.options[rnd].toString()
    }
    if (this.next != null)
        string += this.next.toString()
    return string
}

function parse() {
    text()
    if (index == string.length)
        return

    if (string[index] == "{") {
        index++
        options()
        var next = new Node()
        current.next = next
        current = next
        parse()
    }
}

function options() {
    var parent = current
    while(true) {
        current = new Node()
        parent.options.push(current)
        parse()
        index++
        if (string[index - 1] != '|')
            break
    }
    current = new Node()
    parent.next = current
}

function text() {
    while (index < string.length && "{|}".indexOf(string[index]) == -1) {
        current.text += string[index]
        index++
    }
}

parse()
alert(root.toString())
```

Just a heads up - this doesn't handle these strings:

- "some text { without a closing curly brace"
- "an unexpected | pipe symbol"
- "an unexpected } closing curly brace"

I'll let you add that in yourself.

Comment: I have made a progress with a tree still trying to randomize the inner strings.

Comment: Oh ok. Google the visitor pattern.

Comment: How it should help me here?

Comment: I just realized you're parsing with a regex. Using a regex will select the text, and strip out the extra syntax characters, but it will lose all information about the structure of the tree. You won't know whether part1 is optional along with part2, or if part1 is compulsory, and part2 is optional.

Comment: Andrew please show me the piece of code that will traverse it as I require